# агрегированные функции sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

допустим есть таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как сделать `select`  всех столбцов +столбец в каждой ячейке которого общая сумма SalesYTD по всем `BUsinessEntityID`, т.е. в каждой ячейке этого столбца одно и то же значение `sum(salesYTD)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь отдельным подзапросом, который вернет сумму.

```
select *,
       (select sum(salesYTD) FROM test)
  from test
```

Или предложением `over` (есть ограничения по СУБД, в postgerss должно работать):

```
select *,sum(salesYTD) over ()
  from test
```

Comment: примного благодарен!